# Laravel display image from path which is in database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

So use is uploading a logo and it's path is stored in a database like this:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\public\logo\1496912432.jpg

I am displaying the image like this:

```
<img class="images" id="image" src="{{$business->image}}" />
```

However I get this error:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/public/logo/1496912432.jpg
```

How can this problem be solved?

//edit

Controller:

```
public function image(Request $request) {
    if($request->hasFile('img'))
    {
        $image = Input::file('img');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path = public_path('logo/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image->getRealPath())->fit(303, 200)->save($path);
        $file = $request->file('img');
        $session = session()->get('key');
        $update_image = Business::find($session);
        $update_image->image = $path;
        $update_image->save();
        return ['url' => url('logo/' . $filename)];
    }
```

Comment: I guess "logo\1496912432.jpg" will be enough to store in the db and then you can use asset(your path) like hafiz said. Storing the full path may brake the code on a different environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Laravel `file()` to store files https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#files

Store the $path to your db

```
$path = $request->photo->store('logo');
```

the `$request->photo` is depending on your input file attribute name. In your case, it should be `$request->img`.

the above code will create a folder (if not exist), namely "logo" and store to that folder with random string file name.

Also check your configuration for file, located at `/config/filesystem.php`. Default is set to public

Use `asset` function to get the full path from public folder

```
<img class="images" id="image" src="{{ asset($business->image }}" />
```

Comment: have a look at my controller, how could I modify it to use the way you have suggested?

Comment: @Przemek change it to `$request->img->store('logo')` if your input file name is "img". Config file is at `config/filesystem.php`. The default is 'public' so it will store then and create the 'logo` folder

Answer (score 0):

You can do in two ways

Best way is update url path when image saving save url path to db

```
$path = $request->photo->store('logo'); // in 5.4
```

The other way if you can't changes db url you can do some hack like this

```
$file = explode('/public/', $business->image);
echo asset($file[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to store all files inside the web root. Because of cross-domain security, you cannot access the file:// domain/protocol from a http protcol. By using Laravel to store and retrieve, it will come from the same host.

Comment: cant be it. I can echo images in store on other places from the site. Just the difference in this instance is using vuejs.